# iOS6 NSHTTPCookieStorage deleteCookie issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cookies, uiwebview, ios6

I have a browser app which i use to enter a specific site.

This site (which i don't own) has a bug related only in iOS6. Once you log in into the site, if you try to run the app and login again, it fails.

In safari, if i delete the cookies before the 2nd try, it works. But when i use a UIWebView, it look like the cookies are deleted when i try to print them, but the login still fails.

I used this code to delete the cookies:

```
 NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
 NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
 for (cookie in [cookieStorage cookies]) {
     [cookieStorage deleteCookie:cookie];
     NSLog(@"delete Cookie. Name: %@ : , domain: %@", cookie.name, cookie.domain);
 }
```

It does not happen on iOS5.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

May be... You shouldn't delete object in "for". I think sometimes you have crash.
You should mark some object in "for" and delete object
example:

NSMutableArray *arrayObject = [NSMutableArray array];

NSMutableArray *deleteArray = [NSMutableArray array];

```
for (Someobject *object in arrayObject) {
    [deleteArray addObject:object];
}
[arrayObject removeObjectsInArray:deleteArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *newCookie = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]];

for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
}
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in newCookie) {
    NSMutableDictionary *properties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:cookie.properties];
    [properties removeObjectForKey:NSHTTPCookieExpires];
     NSHTTPCookie *changeCookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:properties];
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:changeCookie];
```

This code is working on iOS5 & iOS6. I checked. I think problem in:
 What will **NSLog** show in last object?

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage;
while (storage.cookies.count > 0) {
    [storage deleteCookie:storage.cookies.lastObject];
}
```